# Javascript Carousel: what's the code that makes a little of the previous image show?

Tags: javascript, carousel

I have a javascript-based carousel on a website, and it's set to automatically cycle through the images from right to left.  On the left side, a little of the previous image shows, but this effect is not on the right side... So where's the code that makes that happen?

Otherwise everything, including the left and right buttons that lay on top of the images, is perfectly centered, so it seems like something intentional in the js code.

Any ideas on what to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like there's nothing wrong with the code...

I fixed this issue by reducing the width of ALL images for the carousel by 2px in the CSS file.

So I went from `width:100px` to `width:998px` and that solved the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the images are inline-blocks. If so, there are a few tricks to remove the extra space, one of which is adding a negative margin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I searched both the CSS file and the JS file for the carousel for "inline-block", but didn't get anything... I looked manually, they're 'display:block'